# Centralizer generators

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-groups, orthogonal-matrices, involutions

This is a question posted on overflow but no reply has been received.

In the algebraic group $G=\operatorname {PSO}(4,K)<\operatorname {PCGO}(4,K)$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field of an odd characteristic, there is a conjugacy class of involutions with representative:
$$
 e=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 w & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & w^{-1} & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & w & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & w^{-1} \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$ where $w$ is of order 4 in $K$.

The centralizer in $G$ is $C_G(e) =T_2.4$. The "4" is a Klein 4-group generated by
$$
 f_1=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right],
 f_2=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right].$$
There is an $$
 f=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]\in \operatorname {PCGO}(4,K) \setminus \operatorname {PSO}(4,K)$$ which also centralizes $e$.

Thus seems like $C_{\operatorname {PCGO}(4,K)}(e)= T_2.4.2$ and the $4.2$ is supposed to be a dihedral group of order 8. But the conjugate action of $f$ on $f_1$ and $f_2$ doesn't seem to give a dihedral group. What is going on here? Thank you!

Edit: $\operatorname{CGO}$ is the subgroup of the general linear group which fixes a non-degenerate quadratic form up to a scalar. $\operatorname {PCGO}$ is the projective group.

Comment: Why do you think $\langle f, f_1,f_2\rangle$ generate a dihedral group? Are you certain there's an actual complement to $T_2$ in the centralizer?

Comment: Thank you for the input. Do you mean the outside group of order $2$? If so, I get it from Prop $2.18$ of Griess' paper "elementary abelian $p$-subgroups of algebraic group"... Also a Klein-4 with an outside $2$ seems most sensibly to give a dihedral...

Comment: Yes, but are you sure the extension is split?

Comment: No, I'm not sure... You are saying it might be elementary abelian of rank 3?

Comment: No I mean the centralizer has a dihedral quotient, but are you sure it has a dihedral subgroup that complements $T_2$?

Comment: OK. I see what you mean. But I'm not quite sure... And I'm running out of info to help me investigate the structure...